# How to use a 2d vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector

What is the correct way to implement an efficient 2d vector? I need to store a set of Item objects in a 2d collection, that is fast to iterate (most important) and also fast to find elements.

I have a 2d vector of pointers declared as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Item*>> * items;
```

In the constructor, I instantiate it as follows:

```
items = new std::vector<std::vector<Item*>>();
items->resize(10, std::vector<Item*>(10, new Item()));
```

I how do I (correctly) implement methods for accessing items? Eg:

```
items[3][4] = new Item();

AddItem(Item *& item, int x, int y)
{
     items[x][y] = item;
}
```

My reasoning for using pointers is for better performance, so that I can pass things around by reference.

If there is a better way to go about this, please explain, however I would still be interested in how to correctly use the vector.

Edit: For clarification, this is part of a class that is for inventory management in a simple game. The set 10x10 vector represents the inventory grid which is a set size. The Item class contains the item type, a pointer to an image in the resource manager, stack size etc.

My pointer usage was in an attempt to improve performance, since this class is iterated and used to render the whole inventory every frame, using the image pointer.

Comment: You want to pass things around by reference by using pointers, instead of using the reference feature already in C++? See the `&` operator when declaring a variable/argument. Also you should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers. Thirdly, have you measured that this will be a bottleneck or are you just doing premature optimizations that might not be needed and unnecessarily complicates the code?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to c++, I'll take a closer look at the & operator, I was under the impression I needed to store things as pointers. This is part of a learning exercise, so I have not looked at smart pointers and am interested in the efficiency.

Comment: _Way_ too much pointers in this code.  Don't use raw pointers.  Owning raw pointers and hard and thus cause mistakes (for instance, in your code, every single element of the 2d array points to the same `Item`), and are also _slower_ than doing it the normal way.  Don't do that.

Comment: Since it is a vector with 2 dimensions, I think you should call it a Matrix. You know the size during compile time (10), so you can use boost array (If you are using C++11, you should consider using std::array) instead of a vector. Since arrays allocate elements on stack and vector on the heap, arrays can have a better performance comparated stl vectors.

Comment: First, don't worry about performance until you've got something that works.  Second, dynamic allocation can be relatively expensive, so dynamically allocating everything is usually not very good for performance.  Third, you can easily have references to things which aren't dynamically allocated.  (You do have to understand lifetime issues, but that's true with dynamic allocation as well.)

Comment: On the other hand, if the class is inherited, and the actual objects in the 2D vector are derived classes, you _must_ use pointers, and probably dynamic allocation.  Just be aware of the lifetime issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you know the size of the matrix beforehand, and that this matrix is squared. Though `vector<>` is fine, you can also use native vectors in that case.

```
Item **m = new Item*[ n * n ];
```

If you want to access position r,c, then you only have to multiply r by n, and then add c:

```
pos = ( r * n ) + c;
```

So, if you want to access position 1, 2, and n = 5, then:

```
pos = ( 1 * 5 ) + 2;
Item * it =  m[ pos ];
```

Also, instead of using plain pointers, you can use smart pointers, such as `auto_ptr` (obsolete) and `unique_ptr`, which are more or less similar: once they are destroyed, they destroy the object they are pointing to.

```
auto_ptr<Item> m = new auto_ptr<Item>[ n * n ];
```

The only drawback is that now you need to call `get()` in order to obtain the pointer.

```
pos = ( 1 * 5 ) + 2;
Item * it =  m[ pos ].get();
```

Here you have a class that summarizes all of this:

```
class ItemsSquaredMatrix {
public:
    ItemsSquaredMatrix(unsigned int i): size( i )
        { m = new std::auto_ptr<Item>[ size * size ]; }
    ~ItemsSquaredMatrix()
        { delete[] m; }

    Item * get(unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
        { return m[ translate( row, col ) ].get(); }
    const Item * get(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const
        { return m[ translate( row, col ) ].get(); }

    void set(unsigned int row, unsigned int col, Item * it)
        { m[ translate( row, col ) ].reset( it ); }

    unsigned int translate(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const
        { return ( ( row * size ) + col ); }

private:
    unsigned int size;
    std::auto_ptr<Item> * m;
};
```

Now you only have to create the class `Item`. But if you created a specific class, then you'd have to duplicate `ItemsSquaredMatrix` for each new piece of data. In C++ there is a specific solution for this, involving the transformation of the class above in a **template** (hint: `vector<>` is a template). Since you are a beginner, it will be simpler to have `Item` as an abstract class:

```
class Item {
public:
    // more things...
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};
```

And derive all the data classes you will create from them. Remember to do a cast, though...

As you can see, there are a lot of open questions, and more questions will raise as you keep unveliling things. Enjoy!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my original post to try and clarify everything. Using a calculated index seems to be quite popular, I would have thought it less preferred due to the index calculations. I will look into unique_ptr, until now I've been under the impression that I should be managing raw pointers for everything myself, which I now assume is an archaic way of doing things?

Comment: It is not that it is archaic, it is a way of looking for problems when you have mechanisms that, although being simple and not as powerful as a garbage collector (and also without consuming resources), they automatically correct many potential problems related to memory management (mainly memory leaks related to forget to 'delete'memory). This is based on the constructor/destructor methods being automatically called with the creation and destruction of objects. The more general pattern based on this is RAII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Answer (score 2):

For numerical work, you want to store your data as locally as possible in memory. For example, if you were making an `n` by `m` matrix, you might be tempted to define it as

```
vector<vector<double>> mat(n, vector<double>(m));
```

There are severe disadvantages to this approach. Firstly, it will not work with any proper matrix libraries, such as `BLAS` and `LAPACK`, which expect the data to be contiguous in memory. Secondly, even if it did, it would lead to lots of random access and pointer indirection in memory, which would kill the performance of your matrix operations. Instead, you need a contiguous block of memory `n*m` items in size.

```
vector<double> mat(n*m);
```

But you wouldn't really want to use a `vector` for this, as you would then need to translate from 1d to 2d indices manually. There are some libraries that do this for you in `C++`. One of them is [Blitz++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blitz/), but that seems to not be much developed now. Other alternatives are [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). See [this previous answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library) for more details.

Using `Eigen`, for example, the matrix declaration would look like this:

MatrixXd mat(n,m);

and you would be able to access elements as `mat[i][j]`, and multiply matrices as `mat1*mat2`, and so on.

Comment: If you find a library which does what you need, fine, but if not, the most logical underlying store for your own class is `std::vector`.

Comment: @James Kanze - What I meant was that he shouldn't be using the `vector` *directly*, as it would involve too much manual index-juggling. Building something around a `vector` is fine, though when it comes to linear algebra, you're easily going to be 10 times slower than a good library if you try to implement it yourself, so I recommend against re-inventing the wheel in this case.

Comment: Then I agree.  If the abstraction is a 2D array, `vector` doesn't quite cut it; it's abstraction is a 1D array.  But it's also a very good way of managing a block of memory.  With regards to the libraries, _if_ `Item` is a numeric type of some sort, then you definitely should be using a more advanced mathematical library.  As you say, getting it both right and efficient is decidedly non-trivial.  If it's not, I'm less sure.  They would end up adding a lot of code which in fact couldn't be used (because it supposes the presence of operators like `+` and `*`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight with matrix handling, while not the case with this particular problem, I do value the information. I have updated my original post with the details of the Item class.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is why the pointers.  There's almost never any reason
to have a pointer to an `std::vector`, and it's not that often that 
you'd have a vector of pointers.  You're definition should probably be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Item> > items;
```

, or at the very least (supposing that e.g. Item is the base of a
polymorphic hierarchy):

```
std::vector<std::vector<Item*> > items;
```

As for your problem, the best solution is to wrap your data in some sort
of a `Vector2D` class, which contains an `std::vector<Item>` as member,
and does the index calculations to access the desired element:

```
class Vector2D
{
    int my_rows;
    int my_columns;
    std::vector<Item> my_data;
public:
    Vector2D( int rows, int columns )
        : my_rows( rows )
        , my_columns( columns )
    {
    }

    Item& get( int row, int column )
    {
        assert( row >= 0 && row < my_rows
                && column >= 0 && column < my_columns );
        return my_data[row * my_columns + column];
    }

    class RowProxy
    {
        Vector2D* my_owner;
        int my_row;
    public;
        RowProxy(Vector2D& owner, int row)
            : my_owner( &owner )
            , my_row( row )
        {
        }
        Item& operator[]( int column ) const
        {
            return my_owner->get( my_row, column );
        }
    };
    RowProxy operator[]( int row )
    {
        return RowProxy( this, row );
    }

    //  OR...
    Item& operator()( int row, int column )
    {
        return get( row, column );
    }
};
```

If you forgo bounds checking (but I wouldn't recommend it), the
`RowProxy` can be a simple `Item*`.

And of course, you should duplicate the above for `const`.

Comment: I've edited my original post to clarify my pointer usage, your implementation is interesting, I hadn't thought of calculating index like that.